# Call "Optional#isPresent() before accessing the value

Tags: java, java-stream

I am not able to resolve the error Call `Optional#isPresent()` before accessing the value.

Tried like this:

```
Optional <Long> maxId = trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream()
        .max(subAccountEntityComparator).get().getSubAccountId();

Comparator<SubAccount> subAccountEntityComparator = Comparator
        .comparing(SubAccount::getSubAccountId);
Long maxId = trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream()
        .max(subAccountEntityComparator).get().getSubAccountId();
```

Comment: wouldn't it be *easier* to get all IDs first (`mapToLong`) and then just find the maximum (`max`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Optional.orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) or [`Optional.orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
Long maxId = trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(SubAccount::getSubAccountId))
        .map(SubAccount::getSubAccountId)
        .orElse(0);
```

This maps the result value if the value is present. If not it returns the `orElse()` value or throws an exception if you use `orElseThrow()`.

Here is the `orElseThrow()` example:

```
Long maxId = trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(SubAccount::getSubAccountId))
        .map(SubAccount::getSubAccountId)
        .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

This could be useful if it is an error if no result is found.

If you want to execute something only if the value is present you can use this:

```
Optional<Long> maxId = trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(SubAccount::getSubAccountId))
        .map(SubAccount::getSubAccountId);

if (maxId.isPresent()) {
    // ...
}
```

Or a shorter variant of this:

```
trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(SubAccount::getSubAccountId))
        .map(SubAccount::getSubAccountId)
        .ifPresent(maxId -> {
            // ...
        });
```

Comment: thank u , i tried the same but understood my mistake . im not using map in case of isPresent , so it is giving cast issue , cannot convert long to optional

Comment: You have to use `get()` on the optional to get get actual value, but use `isPresent()` before calling `get()`.

Comment: Or just `OptionalLong maxId = trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream() .mapToLong(SubAccount::getSubAccountId).max();`

Comment: Yes, that's also a good option. Does this solution have a different performance than the other solutions, because of the `LongStream`?

Answer (score 1):

An Optional can contain either a value or a null. If you call `.get()` on an empty Optional (one that has a value of null), you will get an exception.

One way to safeguard against that is to call `.isPresent()` first - and then skip the call to `.get()` if no value is present.

Another way is to use the `.map()` and `.orElse()` methods as described by @SamuelPhilipp.

Comment: tried using .isPresent(), not able to succeed then came to stack overflow. option suggested by @Samuel Philipp is working. want to know if i want to use isPresent how to represent that

Answer (score -1):

```
Optional <Long> maxId = trdObj.getAccount().getSubAccounts.stream()
        .max(subAccountEntityComparator).map(SubAccount::getSubAccountId);
```

Comment: Hi! While this code may solve OP's problem, it is encouraged on SO to explain why the code is a solution. Code only answers are discouraged on SO, as they do not help OP or future visitors in the long run. Thanks!